# Set wingpanel transparency

Tags: wingpanel, desktop

I would like to keep `wingpanel` transparency on maximized windows (in order to display my current wallpaper). Is it possible?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. Open the terminal and copy/paste;

```
nano ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

Add the following;

```
.panel.maximized {

background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);

}
```

Save: [ctrl]+[o]
Exit: [ctrl]+[x]
Logout and login.

Comment: Storm who changes Elementary OS layout almost every day. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option only to disable transparency at all (System settings > Desktop > Appearance > Pannel translucensy) but not to make it transparent when there is a maximized application.